# Set UID as Node Value in Firebase Realtime Database in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using FIrebase Realtime Database and Angular 9 for my project.

Below is the current structure of my Firebase DB.

```
clients
    -M8bGQaBM...
       email:"test@test.com"
       uid:"5gvR...."
```

I want to push the **uid** (i.e. "5gvR....") in place of the push id (i.e. "-M8bGQaBM...").

Below is the service.ts file. Here, data.uid stores the uid.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from "@angular/fire/database";

import * as moment from "moment";
import { User } from "../models/user";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  selectedUser: User = new User();
  users: AngularFireList<User>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.users = this.db.list("clients");
    return this.users;
  }

  getUserById(id: string) {}

  createUser(data: any) {
    data.location = this.location;
    data.createdOn = moment(new Date()).format("X");
    data.isAdmin = false;
    this.users.push(data);
  }
}
```

Please let me know what changes I need to make in the above service.ts file in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want add new object to You Realtime database and if You know "id" of this object, try this:

```
createUser(): void {
  const data = {
  location: this.location,
  createdOn: moment(new Date()).format("X"),
  isAdmin = false,
 }
 this.db.object('clients/' + userid).update(data);
}
```

for test purpose:

```
createUser(): void {
      const data = {[user.uid]: 'Test entry'}
     this.db.object('testobject').update(data);
    }
```

or

```
const msgRef = this.db.database.ref('/').child('clients/' + user.uid);
 msgRef.push().set({
     location: this.location,
     createdOn: moment(new Date()).format("X"),
     isAdmin = false,
    })
```